# Using static_cast in boost::lambda

Tags: c++, boost, casting, boost-lambda

I need to use `boost::lambda` for some conversion.

I've tried this:

```
static_cast<size_t>(boost::lambda::_1 * 60 * 1000)
```

But I've got error:

```
error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'const boost::lambda::lambda_functor' to 'size_t'
```

How to put this conversion inside of lambda?

Comment: [`ll_static_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#idp320765856). Or maybe just [`ret<size_t>` if implicit conversion is sufficient.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.overriding_deduced_return_type).

Comment: Thank you. ll_static_cast is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `boost::phoenix::static_cast_` instead (and I suggest using Phoenix for lambda expressions in general, assuming you're using c++03).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/phoenix/object/static_cast.hpp